# Where is Arduino Serial created?

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino

Looking through the code I can't see where Serial is created. There is a Serial_ class, but Serial does not seem to be made from that. When the program starts you can start using Serial like it already exists, never having to create a new object out of it. I am looking around inside the arduino code, but have come up empty seeing any actual Serial class that Serial could be a static member of. Anyone know where it might be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, serial is defined [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp#L488):

```
HardwareSerial Serial(&rx_buffer, &tx_buffer, &UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR, RXEN, TXEN, RXCIE, UDRIE, U2X);
```

and over [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h#L98):

```
extern HardwareSerial Serial;
```

HTH

Comment: Ah, well that seems to be the case in the hardware/arduino/avr directory, but not in the sam board's directory I was looking in. I think I ended up finding it in variaht.h which wasn't in cores which was why I couldn't find it. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 4):

The Arduino libraries follow this somewhat unusual pattern of creating an instance of objects for you.  The *Serial* object is created in the HardwareSerial.cpp file, near the end is a section that contains a mass of switches for the various hardware types:

```
in HardwareSerial.cpp
// Preinstantiate Objects //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Those lines are the definition of the variable *Serial* which is where the object is created.

This is helpful for some people because the object instance *Serial* just magically exists.

This library is always included in the core, so your next question should be doesn't this waste memory by forcing the *Serial*?  The answer is no, because if your code (.INO) does not reference *Serial*, then the linker will remove the object from the final binary.  Any one line that does reference the *Serial* variable will cause the linker to keep this pre-instantiated object in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to Arduino version 1.8.5

First Refer HardwareSerial.h and you will see following lines:

```
#if defined(UBRRH) || defined(UBRR0H)
  extern HardwareSerial Serial;
  #define HAVE_HWSERIAL0
#endif
#if defined(UBRR1H)
  extern HardwareSerial Serial1;
  #define HAVE_HWSERIAL1
#endif
```

Then Refer HardwareSerial0.cpp. You will see following code:

```
#if defined(UBRRH) && defined(UBRRL)
  HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRRH, &UBRRL, &UCSRA, &UCSRB, &UCSRC, &UDR);
#else
  HardwareSerial Serial(&UBRR0H, &UBRR0L, &UCSR0A, &UCSR0B, &UCSR0C, &UDR0);
#endif
```